# What is a PolicyException? I can't find any info on this for Android

Tags: android, android-service, android-backup-service

When my app tries to backup its data using the BackupTransportService, I get this error in my stack trace.  I can't find any information about it online and therefore can't figure out why my backup is failing. Any ideas?

```
11-13 19:53:44.481: D/PerformBackupTask(352): starting agent for backup of BackupRequest{pkg=com.NsouthProductions.gradetrackerpro}
11-13 19:53:44.501: I/BackupManagerService(352): got agent android.app.IBackupAgent$Stub$Proxy@441b7118
11-13 19:53:44.501: D/PerformBackupTask(352): invokeAgentForBackup on com.NsouthProductions.gradetrackerpro
11-13 19:53:44.511: V/BackupServiceBinder(30648): doBackup() invoked
11-13 19:53:44.511: D/GradeTracker.MyBackupAgent(30648): onBackup called
11-13 19:53:44.511: D/BackupHelperDispatcher(30648): handling existing helper 'GradeTracker.db' android.app.backup.FileBackupHelper@425a93e0
11-13 19:53:45.382: E/BackupTransportService(352): com.google.android.backup.BackupRequestGenerator$PolicyException: server error in app com.NsouthProductions.gradetrackerpro: code 7
11-13 19:53:45.382: E/BackupTransportService(352):  at com.google.android.backup.BackupRequestGenerator.parseResponse(BackupRequestGenerator.java:360)
11-13 19:53:45.382: E/BackupTransportService(352):  at com.google.android.backup.BackupTransportService.sendRequestLocked(BackupTransportService.java:849)
11-13 19:53:45.382: E/BackupTransportService(352):  at com.google.android.backup.BackupTransportService.access$600(BackupTransportService.java:78)
11-13 19:53:45.382: E/BackupTransportService(352):  at com.google.android.backup.BackupTransportService$1.finishBackup(BackupTransportService.java:444)
11-13 19:53:45.382: E/BackupTransportService(352):  at com.android.server.BackupManagerService$PerformBackupTask.operationComplete(BackupManagerService.java:2320)
11-13 19:53:45.382: E/BackupTransportService(352):  at com.android.server.BackupManagerService$BackupHandler.handleMessage(BackupManagerService.java:572)
11-13 19:53:45.552: I/PerformBackupTask(352): Backup pass finished.
```

Comment: many similar questions in SO, but no solution yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it! My Android Backup Service key was apparently bad. My package name in my manifest has a few capital letters in it so I thought "maybe I should make sure my key was generated with a package name with the same capitalization."  So I registered again with a direct copy/paste of my package name from my manifest and I got a different key which now seems to be working.